# Simple Dimple graph not showing :( beginner mistake most likely

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I know the .tsv file exists and on my python server it gets served with 200.

For some reason i just dont see any graph appear :(

Can someone see the beginner mistake i made ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.6.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
      d3.tsv("bbd2.tsv", function (data) {
        var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
        myChart.setBounds(75, 30, 490, 330)
        myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "avg");
        myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "bmi");
        y.addOrderRule("Date");
        myChart.addSeries( ["name","handedness"], dimple.plot.bubble);
        myChart.addLegend(180, 10, 360, 20, "right");
        myChart.draw();
      });
  </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle or the content of bbd2.tsv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a deeper problem but it looks like you've cut and pasted an example and left this line in by mistake:

```
 y.addOrderRule("Date");
```

You can delete the line, you don't have a variable called `y` and you can't order measure axes.

If it still doesn't work you'll need to post a fiddle because it might be a problem in the data.

Comment: All i have to figure out now is how to combat overplotting.. reading for like an hour on the documentation